# properties in the war didn't get resolve when creating using shrinkwrap

Tags: maven, jboss, shrinkwrap

I am trying to build war file using shrinkwrap as follows for integration test using `Arquillian`.

```
WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(MavenImporter.class).loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").importBuildOutput().as(WebArchive.class);
```

On deployment, I am getting error like

```
address: ([("deployment" => "oss.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"oss.war#primary\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.${datasource_JNDI_Name}]"]}
```

`${datasource_JNDI_Name}` is a variable whose value is there in the pom file.

I guess, the problem is
In the WAR file,The variable which are there in `jboss-web.xml`, `persistence.xml` etc. which is dependent on maven properties are not getting resolved.

Please advise why there are not getting resolved in WAR file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I know that may be a little late for you but could help someone else so there we go:

I had a similar problem declaring my context on my glassfish-web.xml that was resolved by maven-war-plugin with property ${project.artifactId}.

As we copy some dependencies as persistence.xml, for example, during shrinkwap.create this isn't resolved by maven filtering.

There is two ways that I could find that worked:

1: Mapping your directory as resources/testResources and add filtering. This only works if you use some maven-plugin or maven process that is resolved through shrinkwap-resolver/Maven.resolver() mounting your archive.

2: (I've gone this way) As we see in Arquillian remote examples, persistence.xml is duplicated as test-persistence.xml and replaces original persistence.xml during shrinkwrap packaging process. I've copied my glassfish-web.xml as test-grassfish-web.xml into src/test/resources-glassfish-remote and defined a fixed value for my test context using

```
.addAsWebInfResource("test-glassfish-web.xml", "WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml")
```

to place it "manually resolved" into my WebArchive. Guess this is not the most elegant way to solve this problem but saved me a lot of time and worked fast and fine.

You can find complete examples using test-persistence.xml here http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started_rinse_and_repeat/ and here https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-examples

Hope it helps somebody avoid troubles and time lost researching this unsolved maven properties on shrinkwrap deployments.